# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (EXC_i386_GPFLT) when inserting node in BST

Tags: c++, xcode, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to populate Binary Search tree from given array in XCode via C++.
I'm using recursion to generate BST in following way.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const int length = 19;
        int data[length] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        Node* root = new Node(12);

        for(int i = 0;i<length;i++){
            insert(data[i], &root);
        }
return 0;
}
```

and here is my insert function

```
void insert(int key, Node **current)
{
    if(*current == NULL)
    {
        Node *newnode = new Node(key);
        *current = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        if(key < (*current)->value) ---------EXCEPTION HERE
            insert(key, &(*current)->left);
        else
            insert(key, &(*current)->right);
    }
}
```

sometimes it throws an exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = EXC_i386_GPFLT).
The same logic works fine in Visual Studio with C#.
Am i doing something wrong with memory in c++?
I'm not so much familiar with c++, but seems everything should work.

Comment: You must show the declaration and the definition of the `Node` class. The most likely answer is that `left` and `right` are not getting explicitly initialized to `nullptr`.

Comment: exactly!. it was 
Node(int _value){
        value = _value;
    }

Comment: you can write  it as an answer that i could mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying the Sherlock Holmes approach to bug hunting(1), the most likely explanation was that `left` and `right` class members were not getting explicitly initialized to `nullptr`.

(1) "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth."